# Bootstrap 3 override navbar color not working when theme min css included

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap navbar menu color override not working when i include bootstrap-theme-min.js

without bootstrap-theme.min.css:

[image]

with bootstrap-theme.min.css:
[image]

how to override when bootstrap-theme.min.css included on page.

```
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(250, 245, 245, 1);
}
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(58, 8, 158, 0.86);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(245, 231, 231, 1);
    background-color: rgba(245, 82, 17, 1);
}
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(245, 233, 233, 1);
    background-color: rgba(242, 75, 9, 1);
}
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #f24b09;
}
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #f24b09;
}
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #f24b09;
}
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #3a089e;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek462/jqdtae7x/)

Comment: @Downvoters please mention in comment, the reason for close vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `background-color` property, use `background` on this:

```
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default { background-color: rgba(58,8,158,0.9); }
```

to

```
#my-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default { background: rgba(58,8,158,0.9); }
```